# What is the point of phonegap-build/PushPlugin? Doesn't the device OS handle receipt from GCM/APNs?

Tags: cordova, drupal, google-cloud-messaging, push, apn

What is the point of phonegap-build/PushPlugin? Doesn't the device OS handle receipt from GCM/APNs?

I'm looking to use Drupal w/Push-Notifications Module to handle storing ids and forming requests to the GCM/APNs servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your Cordova/PhoneGap app can use push notifications, you need to do some setup work like registering with the server and retrieving the token. The plugin provides an easy way to do that setup work in Javascript without having to write the code yourself for each platform you want to support (they're all significantly different from one another).